# Fixing Border Radius in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, css

I'm in a bit of a problem here. I can't seem to get the border-bottom-radius-left and right to work properly on Safari. I took screenshots of the border radius on 3 browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari). Only Safari had the trouble.

---

**Google Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

---

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

---

**Safari**

[image: Safari]

---

From there, you can pretty much tell the problem. I used `border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;` and `border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;`. However, the two top radius properties seem to be working fine.

I'm kinda stuck because I'm not sure how to fix this. By the way, I'm talking about Safari Version 5.1.2 (6534.52.7).

Comment: I believe `120px` is too big for your element, isn't it...

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: When the value is bigger than the allowed width/height, it will be capped at either width or height, whichever allows it. That's probably not the issue here as Safari is usually able to handle such a case.

Comment: Daniel A. White, Thanks for reminding, I've updated my post now. Alexander Pavlov, I wanted to give it a wide arch.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, I'm in no way insinuating this is the culprit. Chromium and Safari use different painting engines (as opposed to "rendering engine", as WebKit is often called): Skia for Chromium, err... Cairo? for Safari, and that might be the issue with Safari's interpretation of this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Safari bug to me. Caused by using a `border-radius` larger than your elements `height`.

Easy fix; set the `border-radius` to match the element's `height`. I can't see a reason to make it larger anyway.

If for some reason you need an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zejQX/

EDIT

You can supply more than one value to achieve different results:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 150px 50px;
```

Here's an example with a "wide arch" as requested below: http://jsfiddle.net/BpJ7v/3/

Comment: That fixed it but the reason it's way up is because I wanted it to create a wide arch.

Comment: you can supply more than one value to achieve that. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/BpJ7v/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

to your element that has the border radius.

See http://goo.gl/ywAa1